# Adding data to a text file on a server - iOS

Tags: ios, file, nsurlconnection

I have a text file that needs to be updated with a string on a IBAction. Will using NSURLConnection help ? or is there any other way to do this? The url used is http://spider90.dyndns.org:8080/sid/test.txt

Comment: Your question title and content are talking about different things. Please clarify and be precise about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to add a string to text file on the server using iOS. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think a more simple approach would be to use NSString's built in function

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

Just instantiate a string with the url and proper encoding and you have the text file.
Good luck!

BTW the link you attached is broken

Comment: Hello thanks a lot! Is there a way to pass the string input? Like if i want add string "hello", is there a function that lets me use it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? What do you mean by "pass the string input"?